# How can I make square and triangular rings?

Tags: modeling, bevel

I'm new to Blender and trying to make two simple objects: square and triangular rings.

I started with a square object (using a cube) and applied bevel on its edges. Unfortunately, this is the best I could achieve after hours of work. I could not find good tutorials on that either. How can I do this?

[image]

[image]

This is an example of what I am trying to make:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Edited my post.

Comment: Did you try with curves?

Comment: Just want to thank everyone for their input! Very informative and helpful!

Answer (score 15):

You can also do it with geometry nodes... lazy approach...

[image]

Some explanations:

- Mesh to curve: transforms a mesh to a curve, removing faces and just keeping edges as splines.
- Fillet curve: for "poly" option bevels the curve vertices on a given radius and divisions count.
- Curve to mesh: generate a mesh from the curve given a profile curve (here a circle).

[image]

Little enhancements, in the file below. I've added "profile resolution" for a default circle profile, the possibility to use another profile and a flag to shade smooth or not the result.

[image]

The corresponding blend file:
[image]

Comment: very nice! damn i went the over complicated way lol

Comment: +1 even if i find it very unexplained

Comment: @moonboots, yep ; )

Comment: why are geometry nodes needed - isn't there a modifier which does this to a curve? and why use "mesh to curve" instead of having a curve to begin with?

Comment: @user253751, just a way to do it. One can do it directly with a curve, but with these nodes filets are here only when needed, not all along the curve depending on its resolution.

Answer (score 8):

If you enable the shipped add-on: *Add Curve: Extra Objects*, you get curve polygons.  You can then (right-click menu) fillet their corners, switch them to 3D, and their Fill Mode to 'Full' in their 'Shape' panel, and use their native Round Bevel to thicken them in their 'Geometry' panel..

[image]:

... maybe give a level of Subdiv.

But I wound up having to go backwards and forwards a bit to get satisfactory topology in the fillets, matching thicknesses, etc.. [@Lemon's way](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/289011/35559) is better, IMO.

Or.. easier to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> bevel the vertices of a  3-point mesh-circle, or any other faceless mesh-edge shape, convert to a curve, and go from there, with the curve's native Bevel.

Answer (score 5):

Add a plane and a circle with 3 sides, join them with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> (or you could do them one at a time as well if you wish), go to *Edit mode* and bevel all geometry with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to your liking, then convert the object to curve in *Object mode* and add some bevel depth in the curve properties. You can add more resolution to the curve to make it smoother and then convert to mesh again for further editing if needed. You might want to set shading to smooth as well.

[image]

Comment: What's going on with other answers?.. Do we really need add-ons, geometry nodes or so much modelling for something this simple?.. What next? Python script and displacing a sphere with shader nodes? :D Sure it's fun, but why not start with the simple everyday kind of stuff?..

Comment: Martynas, I just did it this way reacting to Harry much too complicated way to do it. Though, gn solution is very flexible...

Comment: I just think the first answer should have been the simple one that's all. :D GN solution is actually very nice and the add-on is nice to know about as well for sure.

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys I'm sure that all these answers including my weird approach have made the OP more knowledgable. If it was just 1 simplest and fastest answer, he and future learners would have never known the other stuff existed and that there are more ways to solve a problem and besides, what if geometry nodes or an addon was the approach he preferred but nobody introduced it :)

Answer (score 4):

Add a plane and <kbd>tab</kbd> into *Edit Mode* then press <kbd>A</kbd> then <kbd>M</kbd> *> Merge At Center*. There will be one vertex left at the center. Select it and press the sequence <kbd>E</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>-</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> to *Extrude* along the X-axis by negative 1 unit. Select the center vertex again and then use the sequence <kbd>E</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> to extrude another vertex along the Y-Axis by 1 unit. Then use this extruding technique two times more to extrude another 2 vertices to, say, 0.8 units.

[image]

Delete the center vertex by selecting it and pressing <kbd>X</kbd> *> Delete > Vertices*. Temporarily extrude the whole setup by a small amount on the Z-Axis so you get the following shape. Select the vertices shown below and go to *Edge > Bridge Edge Loops*

[image]

Tinker around with the settings in the [`Adjust Last Operation`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/undo_redo.html#adjust-last-operation) popup to get the profile you need.

[image]

Press <kbd>A</kbd><kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> to scale the vertices back to zero on the Z-axis. Press <kbd>A</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> *> Merge By Distance* to merge all vertices.

[image]

Add a *Mirror Modifier* for X & Y and <kbd>tab</kbd> back into *Object Mode*. Right click the object and select *Convert To* > *Curve*

[image]

Under *Curve Settings* go to *Bevel* tab and give it some *Depth* and adjust the *Resolution*. Right click object and select *Convert To > Mesh*.

[image]

You can do the same technique for the triangle. Just leave a small gap between the 3 corners and let the *Bridge Edge Loops* step round those corners.

Comment: What the heck are you doing to get a square with rounded corners... or do you just want to show Igor how many different tools Blender has? Add a plane, in _Edit Mode_ delete _Only Faces_, select the vertices and press Ctrl+Shift+B to bevel them... and for the triangle: add _Mesh_ > _Circle_ with 3 vertices and bevel them.

Comment: even no need to delete the face before converting to curve...

Comment: with bevel you can only get 1 curvature shape. but what if you wanted another profile? but yeah if you don't like the solution, just downvote it, as simple as that guys :)

Comment: I can't downvote it, I upvoted it ;) But well, the bevel only makes rounded corners - it has nothing to do with the overall shape. You also don't have to extrude upwards to bevel the corners... and he asked for square and triangular rings, it does not seem he needed to know how to get the general shape, just making it a ring and rounding the corners.

Comment: ...oh, and a bevel can have more than just a simple curvature shape ;)

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't know that XD so yeah i extruded it on the z coz i couldn't get the Bridge Edge Loops to work.

Comment: that was a reply to @GordonBrinkmann first comment.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann i got 98/100 sportsmanship badge. please add your answers guys so i can upvote :D

Comment: @lemon Of course you are right, that was kind of an "aesthetic" decision to delete the face :D

Comment: ok... I'll push an answer ; )

Comment: I'm at work, a quick comment here and there is no problem, but an answer with screenshots etc. has to wait... @lemon can do it

Comment: Yes not sure why you made it so complicated...

Comment: I totally forgot about beveling since i think of beveling mostly in 3D. in this case it was a flat surface and beveling didn't come up in my funny brains ;)

Comment: I don't think that's a very good answer to be honest. It's a bit misleading as that's way more complex than it needs to be.

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys yes thanks for the downvote :)